# Where do App Store & Game Center facebook Likes go?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, facebook-like, game-center

I'm trying to understand why it seems the "Like" buttons built into iOS 6 don't seem to go anywhere. I've developed a couple of apps and have linked them to their own facebook page. I would expect that when a user like my app from the App Store or Game Center, that it would reflect their like on the app's facebook page... but it doesn't!

Anyone have any insight to this?

Comment: When I liked my game it seemed to hook into a special pseudo page which takes you directly to the app store when you click on it.

Comment: Which like button did u click?

Comment: The Game Center like button.